# Apache POI - How to set correct column width in Word table

Tags: apache-poi

I have an existing Word document containing a table.  The first row of the table has two cells, but all the other rows have four cells and each cell has a different width.

I need to insert new rows via POI that also have four cells with widths that match those of the existing 4-cell rows.

The basic code is:

```
XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);

XWPFTableRow oldRow = table.getRow(2);
table.insertNewTableRow(3);
XWPFTableRow newRow = table.getRow(3);

XWPFTableCell cell;
for (int i = 0; i < oldRow.getTableCells().size(); i++) {
    cell = newRow.createCell();
    CTTblWidth cellWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    BigInteger width = oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getW();

    cellWidth.setW(width);  // sets width

    XWPFRun run = cell.getParagraphs().get(0).createRun();
    run.setText("NewRow C" + i); 

}
```

The result of this is that row 3 has four cells but their widths do not match those of row 2.  The total new row width ends up being the same as the total width of the first three cells of row 2.  (Sorry, I don't know how to paste the Word table here).

However, if I first manually edit the source document so that the first table row also has four cells, then everything works perfectly.  Similarly, if I get a reference to an existing row and add it to the table, then the cell widths are also correct (but I have the same row object twice so can't modify it).

It seems that the number of cells in the first row influences how other rows are inserted.  Does this make sense to anyone and can you suggest how to override it?  Also, is there a document anywhere that I can study to understand how this works?  Thanks.

Comment: The table code is a little funky right now. It adds cells with blank paragraphs for you so your code might be adding on to the end of the row created by `table.insertNewTableRow(3)` which will have one cell containing a paragraph to start out with. You will currently have to look at code. You could try the newest version which might work a bit more nicely, but I don't think it has fixes for table code yet. Best bet is to debug through it to determine what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordiing to your mention: "The first row of the table has two cells, but all the other rows have four cells and each cell has a different width." I suspect this will be a very messy table. Although `Word` is supporting such tables, I would try to avoid such. But if it must be, you need to know that there is a table grid also for those messy tables. Unzip the `*.docx` and have a look at `/word/document.xml` there you will find it.

So if we want to insert rows into such messy tables, we also must respect the table grid. For this there is a `GridSpan` element in the `CTTcPr`. This we must also copy from the `oldRow` and not only copy the `CTTblWidth`.

Also the `CTTblWidth` has not only a width but also a type. This we also should copy.

Example:

The `source.docx` looks like this:

[image]

As you see the table grid has 10 columns in total. "Cell 2 1" spans 3 columns, "Cell 2 2" spans 3 columns, "Cell 2 3" spans 0 columns (is its own column), "Cell 2 4" spans 3 columns.

With code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordInsertTableRow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));

  XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);

  XWPFTableRow oldRow = table.getRow(2);
  table.insertNewTableRow(3);
  XWPFTableRow newRow = table.getRow(3);

  XWPFTableCell cell;
  for (int i = 0; i < oldRow.getTableCells().size(); i++) {
   cell = newRow.createCell();

   CTTcPr ctTcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();

   CTTblWidth cellWidth = ctTcPr.addNewTcW();
   cellWidth.setType(oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getType());  // sets type of width
   BigInteger width = oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getW();
   cellWidth.setW(width);  // sets width

   if (oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan() != null) {
    ctTcPr.setGridSpan(oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan()); // sets grid span if any
   }

   XWPFRun run = cell.getParagraphs().get(0).createRun();
   run.setText("NewRow C" + i); 
  }

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("result.docx"));
  doc.close();

  System.out.println("Done");

 }
}
```

The `result.docx` looks like:

[image]

Comment: Axel Richter - a very useful answer.  Unzipping the .docx was new to me and will be very helpful in solving future problems.

Comment: What I'm basically trying to do is insert a row with similar characteristics to the row above it, but modify the text, font and shading.  Ideally there would be a "copy row" function that would perform a deep clone of the  width, width type, grid span, borders and paragraphs / runs objects.  Presumably this does not exist and it's up to me to implement this cloning for any objects I wish to modify?

Comment: Yes, `apache poi` in general and `XWPF` in special is highly in development until now. So maybe this copy row method will exists in future. But in current versions it does not exist. So yes, you will need to implement it yourself. Also the low level objects `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` are needed often. For me [http://grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/) has proved to be a good source of documentation. There all objects and methods are linked and so one can move from method to method by mouse click.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I'll definitely follow up as I'm keen to learn and understand the underlying object model and how it relates to the unzipped .docx file.


Another link I found helpful is [here](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-copy-a-table-and-modify-it-correctly-in-the-same-docx-file-using-POI-tp5716551.html).  This shows how to "clone" a table or row which I could then modify using the various techniques you highlighted.